# How to use the YARD server to show private method?

Tags: yard

My first question I found the `--private` switch is not work for `yard server`, so how to make it work?

Second, I noticed that `--private` switch works for `yard doc`, if I choose to use the `yard doc` to generate doc files instead of using the `yard server`, How to make the rendering document have the frame (side bar)

Comment: '--private` is not an option for `yard server`.  Something to recommend or submit for the next version...  What are you referring to when you mention "rendering document have the frame (side bar)"

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question: You can create a `.yardopts` file with `--private` and `yard server` will respect it.

One caveat is that after documentations is generated for a method, if you subsequently make it private you will need to delete the cache (`rm -rf .yardoc`) then restart `yard server`.